# unable to get the Customer Custom Attribute value in customer_register_success event in magento 2

Tags: event-observer, customer-attribute, magento2.4.5

In my project a custom customer attribute was using and save the value in the table on customer registration. Attribute id was **phone_number**

I want to get this phone number value and send an sms using another module, Event is `customer_register_success`

In my sms module i am trying to get the attribute value by this

```
if($myCustomAttribute = $customer->getCustomAttribute('phone_number')) {
     $mobileNumber =  $myCustomAttribute->getValue();
     $this->logger->critical("phone number Is".$mobileNumber);
}else{
     $this->logger->critical("No phone number available");
}
```

Every time i try to register i am getting the message as this **No phone number available**. But the phone number value was saved in the `customer_entity_varchar` table and after redirection i can see the phone number from customer dashboard too.

Which thing prevent me here to access this phone number on this event call? Can you please suggest me a better way to approach this. Kindly note this phone_number attribute is a Custom customer attribute and set value from another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used

```
$phoneNumber = $customer->getData( 'phone_number');
```

instead of

```
$customer->getCustomAttribute('phone_number')->getValue();
```

worked for me.